# Error with sorting an indexed pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I am having trouble sorting a pandas Series that comes from a data frame.  I have copy and pasted, and altered if need be, code from different [websites](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and stack overflow posts, but none of them sorted the Series.  It doesn't change at all.

As seen below, the variable `dataFile` is a DataFrame, and the variable `data` is a Series.
[image: types]

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
filename = "students.csv"
dataFile = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = 0)
attribute = 'Weight'
data = dataFile.loc[:][attribute]

data.sort_values(axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', ignore_index=False)
print(data)
```

I have tried to sort both the Series and DataFrame to no avail.  Here are some images of the DataFrame and Series respectively:

[image: dataframe]

[image: data]
[image: data2]

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: You specify `inplace=False` and also do not assign the result back to anything so you throw away that entire operation. do `data = data.sort_values(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dropna() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712002/pandas-dropna-function-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = data.sort_values(...)` should work.

Comment: @Jooeey Thank you so much.  I've spent 3+ hours working on this program (not just sorting it), and it finally works.

Answer (score 0):

Try Parameter (inplace = True). It performs operation in-place. If you select False it will not change the data in memory. So, when you are printing the data in the last line, it is showing the previously saved data where no change is made.

Try:

`data.sort_values(axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)`